# If statement nested in For loop - Getting error = The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to write a if statement nested in a for loop for my data frame, which looks like the below:

[image]

I want the code to iterate through each row of the dataframe and if it detects "CV22" in the column Detection_Location, it should import one file as dataframe and if it detects "CV23" in column Detection_location, it should import another file as the same dataframe as earlier.

I have tried writing the below code for doing this:

```
def Get_PHD(df2):
    if (df2['Detection_Location'] == 'CV22'):
           PHD_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\s.gaur\Desktop\LS1 - Edited file.xlsx', sheet_by_name = "Sheet1")
           return (PHD_df)
    elif (df2['Detection_Location'] == 'CV23'):
           PHD_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\s.gaur\Desktop\LS2 - Edited File.xlsx', sheet_by_name = "Sheet1")
           return (PHD_df)



for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    Get_PHD(df2)
```

But getting the following error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anyone please help as in what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Screenshots of data aren't that helpful for reproducing; [Provide a copy of the DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-do-i-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-my-existing-dataframe)

Comment: @Trenton_M - The dataset is actually as small as visible in the picture. There is nothing more to it actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the row to the Get_PHD function and calling the Detection_Location from the row:

```
def Get_PHD(row):
    if (row.Detection_Location == 'CV22'):
           PHD_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\s.gaur\Desktop\LS1 - Edited file.xlsx', sheet_by_name = "Sheet1")
           return (PHD_df)
    elif (row.Detection_Location == 'CV23'):
           PHD_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\s.gaur\Desktop\LS2 - Edited File.xlsx', sheet_by_name = "Sheet1")
           return (PHD_df)


for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    Get_PHD(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

THis is not a valid Boolean expression:

```
if (df2['Detection_Location'] == 'CV22'):
```

`df2['Detection_Location']` is a column of data, not an atomic element.  Thus, the `if` cannot be accurately evaluated as either `True` or `False`.  Hence your error message.

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop that you have you pass DataFrame to `Get_PHD` function, so the part `df2['Detection_Location'] == 'CV22'` is a Series with boolean values.

Just change the loop to:

```py
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    Get_PHD(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Get_PHD(row):
    value = row.Detection_Location
    states = {'CV22': {'file': r'C:\Users\s.gaur\Desktop\LS1 - Edited file.xlsx', 'sheet': 'Sheet1'},
              'CV23': {'file': r'C:\Users\s.gaur\Desktop\LS2 - Edited File.xlsx', 'sheet': 'Sheet1'}}

    try:
        return pd.read_excel(states[value]['file'], states[value]['sheet'])
    except (KeyError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
        print(e)

for _, row in df2.iterrows():
    Get_PHD(row)  # the code example has df2 here, not row
```

- `try`, `except` is included on the possibility you're dealing with more conditions that stated.

  - if you miss a `Detection_Location` or if the file path is incorrect, the code will notify you
- this code is more efficient in that new locations only need to be added to `states`